# Printing SharePoint list items individually

Tags: 2013, list, printing

What would be the best/easiest way to print SharePoint list items individually?

At the moment, when I click print in the browser tools, the print preview contains a virtually blank page, then the data of the item appears half-way down the second page of the print preview.

Would there be a solution to enable printing out/saving to PDF of individual items so it looks something like the picture below?

[image: SharePoint 2013 individual list item view]

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional button in the list form to print the list item.

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:window,print()" value="Print"/>
```

This will print/save as pdf the entire form.

Comment: Thanks. Where would I add this code specifically? On a new page with the list item view as a web part and the javascript in a script editor web part?

Comment: You could add it in View Form of the list using SharePoint Designer

Comment: This works here are the steps to add it to a 'item display' page. 1. open an item in your list 2. edit the page 3. add a web part > media and content > script editor > add 4. click "edit snippet" 5. paste code 6 save page. (stop editing button in page ribbon)